# DocuSign: Composite Template tabs act differently with different accounts

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have a dev(test/demo) and production account for docusign. I am currently sending multiple templates (2) in a single envelope, composite template, both templates have a text tab with the same label name (but different templates). When I send the envelope through the dev account, entering text on one tab does not change the other and vice versa, however, when I send it through the production account whatever changes made to one tab are reflected on the other and vice versa. I am using the exact same templates and witnessing different results as I fill them out on the production account but not the dev. Is this and account based feature that I need to specify?

Comment: You need to use the `DocuSignAPI` tag for developer related questions.  The generic `DocuSign` tag is for general DocuSign service and platform questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention you are "sending the envelope through the dev account" does that mean through the demo Console or through the API?  If it's through the API then there's a trick you need to do.

Let's say you have multiple data (text) field tabs in an envelope and you want them all to update with the same information that the recipient types in.  If you insert the string

```
\\*
```

*before* the `tabLabel` value then all the tabs with the same name will update.  For instance, doing this:

```
"tabs":{
    "textTabs":[
       {
          "tabLabel":"\\*address",
          "value":"123 Main Street"
       },
    ],
 }
```

Would update ALL tabs that have the label of "address" with the value "123 Main Street".